# use php function to list items

Tags: php, mysql

i am tying to do this by  a function. i want every item found in the db to be echoed out as a list

eg. item1
    item2
    item3
    item4

i know im missing something but it is puzzling me. for now im only seeing one list and upon
refresh another item shows up replacing the other. plz help and thanks

```
function get_list() {
 $id = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['id']); 
$get_list = array();
$bar = mysql_query(" SELECT  bar.* FROM bar WHERE bar.b_id = '$id' ORDER BY rand()");
 while($kpl = mysql_fetch_assoc($bar)){
 $get_list[] = array( 'videoid' => $kpl['videoid'],
                'name' => $kpl['name'],
                'description' => $kpl['description'],
                'type' => $kpl['type'],
                'bev' => $kpl['bev'],           
);
}
foreach ($get_list as $get_list);
return $get_list;
}
?>
<?php
$gkp_list = gkp_list();
foreach ($gkp_list as $gkp_list);
if (empty($gkp_list)){ echo 'no video'; }
else { 
echo '<p>$gkp_list['name']. '<br/></p>';}
?>
```

Comment: I don't know why you have the empty foreach inside the get_list function. Also the outer foreach is strange, I think it is better to use different variable name for the array value $gkp_list, for example foreach ($gkp_list as $val) and once again you put a semicolon at the end which causes the foreach to be empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some major syntax problems there.

```
function get_list() {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_GET['id']); 
    $get_list = array();
    $bar = mysql_query(" SELECT  bar.* FROM bar WHERE bar.b_id = '$id' ORDER BY rand()");
    while($kpl = mysql_fetch_assoc($bar)){
        $get_list[] = $kpl;         
    }
    return $get_list;
}

$gkp_list = get_list();
if (empty($gkp_list)) {
    echo 'no video';
} else {
    foreach ($gkp_list as $gkp_item) {
        echo '<p>' . $gkp_item['name']. '<br/></p>';
    }
}
?>
```

1. The purpose of [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) is to loop over an array and do something with each value.  Don't use foreach if you're working with the array as a whole (in this case, returning it)
2. Foreach doesn't have a semicolon at the end, it typically has an opening curly brace (`{`).
3. You don't need to manually copy all of the array indexes in the `while` loop, because all of the indexes are the same.
4. The [string](http://php.net/string) for the output was formatted wrong, you have to be careful.  Use a syntax-highlighting editor.
5. The two variable names in `foreach` must be different.  One refers to the array, and one refers to the value of that key.